# What was the object of Solomon's wisdom?

Tags: king-solomon

Where did the wealth of Solomon's reign come from? I don't know if some noticed, but the reason for the division of the reign was the high tax burden and forced labor, this becomes clear after he dies. So what new institution did Solomon implement so that he would be seen as a notable figure by the media and public opinion? Was his wisdom unable to celebrate an invention that served as a model today in modern societies? I'm playing devil's advocate here, not insulting Jewish literature, but instigating a discussion of what is recorded. Most explanations for the division of kingship are Solomon's love affairs with foreign women that lead to passive idolatry, but the question of taxes and forced labor almost never comes into play. What is the perception of Solomon's reign in Jewish tradition? Was he exemplary or is there criticism that he did not use the wisdom he had to develop better methods to prosper the nation? Did he use his wisdom the way God intended?

Comment: That's a lot of questions. Solomon received a lot of inheritance from David. See Kings I:10:16 and commentaries. I believe his heavy taxes and forced conscription is criticised. Generally Jewish tradition isn't afraid to be critical of its greatest leaders. Solomon's wisdom was exemplary, but he still made mistakes through sin and suffered the consequences in his later years.

Comment: @RabbiKaii 1 Kings 10 mentions the visit of the queen of Sheba and the amount of gold that was brought to Solomon each year, probably from taxes, I don't see David's inheritance there, maybe there's something I'm missing. David in the popular concept is not even known as possessing great fortunes and possessions, that is, the issue of Solomon's wealth seems to have been something in the constancy of his reign.

Comment: The verses show that the physical cause of the split was the high taxes, but the spiritual reason was the sin of idol worship. I don't understand the first part of your question.

Comment: I correlated Solomon's wisdom with his wealth based on the description of his reign as having instituted high taxation and forced labor. Wouldn't that be a misuse of wisdom? Was there not something better to be done to achieve the prosperity of the nation? Raising taxes and forced labor doesn't seem like something extraordinary to me as it was done before like in Egypt

Comment: The criticism after his death was that because he did such great stuff, the people were willing to tolerate the labor drafts; his son was not as great, so the people wouldn't tolerate the same draft. The drafts in and of themselves were not the cause of greatness.

Answer (score 1):

The verses mention his exceptional wisdom concerning the plant and animal kingdoms, and then he obtains the wood and stone from Lebanon to build the Temple by sending Lebanon large amounts of wheat and olive oil. So it would be reasonable to assume that his knowledge of botany/agronomy and veterinary medicine turned Israel into an agricultural powerhouse, which fueled everything from there. It's true that there were labor taxes, but that would only do so much if there wasn't a lot of natural prosperity.

Presumably there was also smart governance and something that enabled seafaring exploration. But I'd start with what's written -- "he spoke about the animals and plants" ... and a few verses later, he is exporting wheat and olive oil.